# Google Tag not sending data to Analytics Dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-tag-manager

I am trying to install tracking codes on two websites via Google Tag Manager. I have added the Google Tag snippet to both sites: legalthree.com and bitcoinattorney.info When I pull up the debug console it appears that the script is loading the Google Analytics tracking correctly. However, no data is reaching the GA dashboard for either site. Any ideas why?

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("create", "UA-2918890-12", {name: "gtm1416506655031", allowLinker: true})
analytics_debug.js:10 Creating new tracker: gtm1416506655031
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm1416506655031.set", "&gtm", "GTM-MD7KQB")
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm1416506655031.set", "anonymizeIp", undefined)
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm1416506655031.set", "hitCallback", [function])
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm1416506655031.send", "pageview")
analytics_debug.js:10 Setting throttling cookie: "_gat_UA-2918890-12"
analytics_debug.js:10 
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j31d&a=1654099982&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fbitcoinattorney.info%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Bitcoin%20Attorney%20.info%20-%20Find%20A%20Bitcoin%20Lawyer%20%26%20Lawyers%20Who%20Accept%20Bitcoin&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1564x801&je=1&fl=15.0%20r0&_u=cACAAAQBI~&jid=1482409291&cid=1927275151.1416501517&tid=UA-2918890-12&_r=1&gtm=GTM-MD7KQB&z=413516838


analytics_debug.js:10 <unknown>        (&gtm) GTM-MD7KQB
analytics_debug.js:10 _j1              (&jid) 1482409291
analytics_debug.js:10 adSenseId        (&a)   1654099982
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 apiVersion       (&v)   1
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 clientId         (&cid) 1927275151.1416501517
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 flashVersion     (&fl)  15.0 r0
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 hitType          (&t)   pageview
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 javaEnabled      (&je)  1
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 language         (&ul)  en-us
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 location         (&dl)  http://bitcoinattorney.info/
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 screenResolution (&sr)  1920x1080
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 title            (&dt)  Bitcoin Attorney .info - Find A Bitcoin Lawyer & Lawyers Who Accept Bitcoin
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 trackingId       (&tid) UA-2918890-12
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 viewportSize     (&vp)  1564x801
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm1416506655031.require", "linker")
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 Plugin "linker" intialized on tracker "gtm1416506655031".
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("gtm1416506655031.linker:autoLink", ["legalthree.com", "bitcoinattorney.info"], false, true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That hit looks correct.

Can you try refreshing the page while viewing the real time reports?

Also make sure your filters/views are excluding the hits and that you are looking at the correct property.

Comment: Thanks, the real time data is coming through. I guess I was thrown off because GA gives "Status: Tracking Not Installed" on the Tracking ID

Comment: Data doesn't get processed for about 24 hours, at which point they would start showing up in Standard reports. In the meantime, as you've already seen, as long as you see the hits in RT reports, then you should be fine.